# Stack glyphicon above text

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my HTML (it can't be changed)

**How to stack the icon above the text? (It should be centered)**

[image]

```css
.quicklinks {
  li {
    a {
      font-size: 10px;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      .glyphicon {
        font-size: 26px;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="quicklinks col-md-offset-8 col-md-4">
  <ul class="list-inline text-right nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="index">
      <a href="/en/index">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home" title="Home"></span> Home
      </a>
    </li>
    <li id="index">
      <a href="/en/index">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" title="User"></span> Home
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add the following CSS which will cause the span to take up 100% of the width, pushing the text below:

```
.glyphicon {
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Also, I'm assuming your code is just an example to reproduce your issue, but in the code you provided you have two `li` elements with the same ID which is [not valid HTML](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).

## [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/a7vW90m4qW)